# Run SQL-server stored procedure with no parameter from python using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc, execute

I am having an issue with running a SQL-server stored procedure from python.

Basically, what the the stored procedure does is take the values from an existing table A, do some operations and store these results in another existing table B. So this procedure has no parameter whatsoever, no input and no output. I am trying to run it from python using pyodbc and while the code does run with no error or exception, the table B (the one that is supposed to take the results) is not updated.

I've tried using "Call" and "execute" but both didn't work. I've tried with other procedures that do have parameters to see if there's something wrong with my code or my connection, and it works perfectly.

So it seems that my problem is only happening with procedures that have no parameter. Any idea how I can get it to work?

Here is an (oversimplified) version of what the procedure is supposed to do :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sptest] as
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON

insert into dbo.test (column1, column2)
values (1, 2)

END
```

When I tried running this from Python, I ran into the same issue (no error but nothing happens). I suspect it's the actual "INSERT" from a remote place that is causing the issue.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does using a `connection.commit()` after everything's done have any effect?  Seeing an example of your code could also be helpful.

Comment: @geekmuse I already have auto-commit set to true in the connection string. Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Yep, you should be covered in that regard, then.

Comment: @geekmuse could there be something specific to add since this stored procedure takes no parameter and has no output set? (btw I have already set NO COUNT ON in the procedure)

Comment: I wouldn't think so, since it sounds like the procedure's being initiated successfully from your Python script.  Does the procedure work as expected if invoked directly?

Comment: @geekmuse Yes. If called in SQL, it works.

Comment: Grasping at straws a bit, but, are you using the same user in both places?  If not, maybe the user from Python doesn't have insert/update privs?

Comment: I'm using "trusted connection = Yes". Wouldn't that take care of it?

Comment: You can use SQL profiler to see what is happening when you run the stored procedure from python..

Comment: @Harry How can I use SQL Profiler?

Comment: @LynnBouNassif If you use SQL Management Studio, click on Tools -> SQL Server Profiler.. connect to the server you want.. have a look at this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29284/how-to-profile-stored-procedures

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using the test code [here](https://pastebin.com/cR0RmHKJ). Please try it (tweaking as required) and see if it works for you.

Comment: I added a snippet of what my code conceptually does (very simplified)

Comment: That's a start. Now can you add some Python code to illustrate how you are invoking the SP? Essentially, you need to create a [mcve] (similar to my test code) that illustrates your problem.